# How do I collapse white space in a list of string that was randomized

Tags: vb.net

I have a list of strings that hold 10 answers.
Each question has a different amount of answers 2-10.
After randomizing the list, I end up with white space or empty spaces in my list depending on the number of answers.

After randomizing the list of let's say 2 answers, i would like to shift them back to position 0 and 1 in my list keeping the size of the list at 10 and of course keeping the order randomized.

I'm not sure how to programmatically solve this problem...

I've tried to sort/reverse the list after randomize, but of course, this removes the randomization.

I've tried to remove the white space with something like

```
answerlist.RemoveAll(Function(str) String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
```

but I then get an out of bounds when trying to write them back to my radiobuttons.text as there are 10 of them.

This is where writing my list of...

```
            RadioAnswer1.Text = answerlist(0)
            RadioAnswer2.Text = answerlist(1)
            RadioAnswer3.Text = answerlist(2)
            RadioAnswer4.Text = answerlist(3)
            RadioAnswer5.Text = answerlist(4)
            RadioAnswer6.Text = answerlist(5)
            RadioAnswer7.Text = answerlist(6)
            RadioAnswer8.Text = answerlist(7)
            RadioAnswer9.Text = answerlist(8)
            RadioAnswer10.Text = answerlist(9)
```

Ideally, I want the list randomized then however many answers there are written back into the list starting at 0 going down to 10.
I hope my question is clear.

Additional info edit

So here is how I'm loading the answers into the List Of..
        Dim answerlist As New List(Of String)

```
    WEFESQLConn.ConnectionString = connectstring
    WEFESQLConn.Open()

    WERESQLStatment.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [WEFE Questions] WHERE QuestionID = " & SQLQuestionNum.ToString
    WERESQLStatment.Connection = WEFESQLConn
    WEFESQLRead = WERESQLStatment.ExecuteReader

    If WEFESQLRead.HasRows Then
        WEFESQLRead.Read()

        lblQuestion.Text = WEFESQLRead.Item("Question").ToString
        answerlist.Add(WEFESQLRead.Item("CorrectAnswer").ToString)
        answerlist.Add(WEFESQLRead.Item("Answer2").ToString)
        answerlist.Add(WEFESQLRead.Item("Answer3").ToString)
        answerlist.Add(WEFESQLRead.Item("Answer4").ToString)
        answerlist.Add(WEFESQLRead.Item("Answer5").ToString)
        answerlist.Add(WEFESQLRead.Item("Answer6").ToString)
        answerlist.Add(WEFESQLRead.Item("Answer7").ToString)
        answerlist.Add(WEFESQLRead.Item("Answer8").ToString)
        answerlist.Add(WEFESQLRead.Item("Answer9").ToString)
        answerlist.Add(WEFESQLRead.Item("Answer10").ToString)

        answerlist.RemoveAll(Function(str) String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))

        WEFESQLRead.Close()
        WEFESQLConn.Close()


        RadioAnswer1.Text = answerlist(0)
            RadioAnswer2.Text = answerlist(1)
            RadioAnswer3.Text = answerlist(2)
            RadioAnswer4.Text = answerlist(3)
            RadioAnswer5.Text = answerlist(4)
            RadioAnswer6.Text = answerlist(5)
            RadioAnswer7.Text = answerlist(6)
            RadioAnswer8.Text = answerlist(7)
            RadioAnswer9.Text = answerlist(8)
            RadioAnswer10.Text = answerlist(9)
```

With this code I get the out of bounds as there are not enough answers to populate the answerlist.

Without

```
answerlist.RemoveAll(Function(str) String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
```

I get the spaces in my pre-drawn radio buttons.
I am all ready hiding the unused buttons - the issue there are 10 positions for the buttons and with the randomization of the list.

[4 spots of 10 used image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRRca.png)

Comment: Why not work out a method that is not dependent on 10 and exactly 10 answers (especially since there is not always 10)?  Post as many answers as there are and stop when you run out of data

Comment: It sounds like you've already collapsed the list to remove the whitespace.  What you really need to do is check each answer and either set the radiobutton##.Text or hide the button if it's Nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you toggle the visibility of the controls dynamically after removing the blank entries from the list? Take a look at this example:

```
'Store all controls in a collection
Dim answers(9) As RadioButton = {RadioAnswer1, RadioAnswer2, RadioAnswer3, RadioAnswer4, RadioAnswer5, RadioAnswer6, RadioAnswer7, RadioAnswer8, RadioAnswer9, RadioAnswer10}

'Iterate through all answers
For index As Integer = 0 To answerlist.Count - 1
    'Show the control and set the text
    With answers(index)
        .Text = answerlist.Item(index)
        .Visible = True
    End With
Next

'Loop through the rest of the answer controls
For index As Integer = answerlist.Count To answers.Length - 1
    'Hide the control
    answers(index).Visible = False
Next
```

Comment: You beat me to it.  I like your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response.. I've updated my original question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

Initial setup...

```
Dim radioButtons As New List(Of RadioButton)
radioButtons.Add(RadioAnswer1)
radioButtons.Add(RadioAnswer2)
...
radioButtons.Add(RadioAnswer10)
```

After removing blank answers from the randomized list...

```
For i = 0 To answerList.Count - 1
    radioButtons(i).Text = answerList(i)
    radioButtons(i).Visible = True
Next
For i = answerList.Count to radioButtons.Count - 1
    radioButtons(i).Visible = False
Next
```

Comment: David beat me to it.  I like his answer better.

Answer (score 0):

To close this out I ended up going with removing all the spaces from my ListOF then using a DO WHILE for each radiobutton.text entries.

example portion

```
 answerlist = RandomizeListOrder(answerlist)
            answerlist.RemoveAll(Function(str) String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))

            Dim ALCount As Integer = answerlist.Count
            Dim ALCounter = 0

            Do

                If ALCounter < ALCount Then
                    ALCounter += 1
                    RadioAnswer1.Text = answerlist(0)
                ElseIf ALCounter = ALCount Then
                    Exit Do
                End If
```

Maybe not very clean as there are 10 of these entries, but I'll work on that later. Just trying to get the idea out.

Thanks everyone for the suggestions they got me on the right path.